# Run multiple applications in Wine

Tags: debian, wine

Am I missing something? I have a Debian Server set up with wine installed (Gnome desktop).

I have a directory called

```
/home/user/apps
```

in here I have my windows exe file `1500.exe`

From the desktop I double click the icon for `1500.exe` and the application opens.

In the directory I then copy and paste the exe file, and rename it to `1501.exe`. But if I double click the new file nothing happens (in fact the 1500.exe window disappears, but is still running).

How can I get both `1500.exe` and `1501.exe` to run at the same time.

Comment: This could be a limitation of the `.exe` and not on `wine`. If you provide additional information of what software it is, you can receive an answer :)

Comment: Well spotted, It doesn't work on Windows either. I think I need to rephrase my question . . .